# VBA comparing collection.count to combobox.value?

Tags: excel, vba

Code works fine when on the active sheet, but when it attempts to use the same code from another sheet, loops infinitely.

I forced a break, and checked the values in the immediate window.

```
? colRAE.count

 187433

? cmbNumberOfRuns

3

? colRAE.count < cmbNumberOfRuns

True
```

My while loop is based on that last part, and seems to be the reason why the loop continues.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Probably not without seeing the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only guess is that you're doing a string comparison. If `cmbNumberOfRuns` is a ComboBox, you're getting the default property by calling it like that - `.Text`.  If colRAE.Count is being interpreted as a String, you'll get the result shown in your question:

```
Sub TextCompare()

    Dim cmbNumberOfRuns As String
    Dim colRAE As String

    cmbNumberOfRuns = "3"
    colRAE = "187433"

    Debug.Print colRAE < cmbNumberOfRuns

End Sub
```

I'd recommend explicitly calling the property of `cmbNumberOfRuns` (both for readability and to avoid repeats of this issue), and explicitly casting to a Long for numerical comparisons:

```
Debug.Print colRAE.Count < CLng(cmbNumberOfRuns.Text)
```

Comment: I think that might work, I'll try it when I get home. I never even considered that the combobox is probably returning the string value of 3. Thanks a lot for the new perspective.